# How to build py3-none-any wheels for a project with an optional C extension?

Tags: python, cython, setuptools, python-wheel, python-extensions

[msgpack](https://pypi.org/project/msgpack/) includes an optional cython
extension. [Some users of the package want py3-none-any wheels of msgpack](https://github.com/ionrock/cachecontrol/issues/160#issue-240767043). I'm trying to figure out how to make
it possible to build wheels both with and without the optional extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use an environment variable in `setup.py` to decide
whether to set `ext_modules` to an empty list of a list of `setuptools.Extension`

## pyproject.toml

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools", "wheel", "cython"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

## setup.py

```py
from setuptools import setup, Extension
import os

if 'ONLY_PURE' in os.environ:
    ext_modules = []
else:
    module1 = Extension('helloworld', sources = ['helloworld.pyx'])
    ext_modules = [module1]
setup(ext_modules=ext_modules)
```

## setup.cfg

```
[metadata]
name = mypackage
version = 0.0.1

[options]
py_modules = mypackage
```

## mypackage.py

```py
try:
    import helloworld
except ImportError:
    print('hello pure python')
```

## helloworld.pyx

```
print("hello extension")
```

## To build with extension:

```sh
$ pip install build
...
$ python -m build
...
$ ls dist/
mypackage-0.0.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl  mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

## To build without extension

```sh
$ pip install build
...
$ ONLY_PURE='a nonempty string' python -m build
...
$ ls dist/
mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl  mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

Comment: What is the outcome of `pip install mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl` ? I don't understand how does `pip` install a wheel that requires an extension without said extension.

Comment: When you run `pip install mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl`. pip only installs `mypackage.py` because (unlike `mypackage-0.0.1-cp39-cp39-linux_x86_64.whl`) `mypackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl` does not contain the **optional** `helloworld` extension. When `mypackage.py` tries to import `helloworld` an `ImportError` is thrown and `mypackage.py` falls back to printing 'hello pure python'

Comment: An optional extension. Ok, I see, thanks! I have an optional extension in one of my packages but I don't provide a wheel without it. Either [binary wheels](https://pypi.org/project/Cheetah3/#files) or a source distribution. The reason to have a pure-source wheel without extension is unclear. Isn't it enough to publish an sdist (.tar.gz)?